# Embedding Maya modelEditor into a PyQt UI

Tags: pyqt, maya, qt-designer

I m getting problem to add modelEditor to QFrame
So plz help me if you can.Thank you

=>Here is my UI created in Qt Designer
http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2944/15230904617_a2b8608d2d_b.jpg

## And here is code to load UI & add functionality

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui

import sip
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic

import maya.cmds as mc
import maya.mel as mm

def getMayaWindow():
    # ‘Get the maya main window as a QMainWindow instance’
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), QtCore.QObject)

def toQtObject(mayaName):
    ”’
    Given the name of a Maya UI element of any type,
    return the corresponding QWidget or QAction.
    If the object does not exist, returns None
    ”’
    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.findControl(mayaName)
    if ptr is None:
        ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.findLayout(mayaName)
        if ptr is None:
            ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.findMenuItem(mayaName)
            if ptr is not None:
                return sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), QtCore.QObject)

uiFile = (‘D:/modEditorTestUI.ui’)
form_class, base_class = uic.loadUiType(uiFile)

class myUIClass(form_class, base_class):

    def __init__(self, parent=getMayaWindow()):
        super(myUIClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi( self )
        self.snapView = mc.modelEditor(displayAppearance=’smoothShaded’, displayTextures=True, wos=False, camera=’persp’)
        qtObj = toQtObject(self.snapView)
        print (‘qtObj: ‘ + str(qtObj))
        #methods
        self.connectSignals()

    def connectSignals(self):
        “”"Connect all the UI signals”"”
        print “Connect signals”

def runUI():
    global app
    global win
    app=QtGui.qApp
    win = myUIClass()
    win.show()

runUI()
```

Comment: In your code you aint even trying to add anything QFrame. What's the problem? (Hello and welcome to [so])

Comment: http://www.kurianos.com/wordpress/?p=692 , http://nathanhorne.com/?p=381

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippet you have provided, it looks like the method toQtObject wouldn't be returning anything useful because of the indentation of the last if and return statements. Here's that fixed:

```
def toQtObject(mayaName):
    """
    Given the name of a Maya UI element of any type,
    return the corresponding QWidget or QAction.
    If the object does not exist, returns None
    """
    ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.findControl(mayaName)
    if ptr is None:
        ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.findLayout(mayaName)
        if ptr is None:
            ptr = apiUI.MQtUtil.findMenuItem(mayaName)
    if ptr is not None:
        return sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), QtCore.QObject)
```